# In Flow, Create a Link to the most recent record for each opportunity record type

Tags: visual-workflow, record-type, url

My users want to have a clickable link on the Contact screen, for the most recent Opportunity Record of each  Opportunity Record Type.

I am using flow, to show the most recent record for each of 5 record types.  I can display the records, but I need help creating each as a link.

Comment: Take a look at this Trailhead tutorial: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_buttons_links

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to describe what you have tried and where you are stuck.  Have you tried a formula element with a `HYPERLINK()` function?